# Worth converting NSMutable<T> to NS<T>

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I know the basics of memory management, but not the internals of how iOS handles the different datatypes. Something always nags me that it's best to use an `NSData` vs `NSMutableData` or `NSString` rather than an `NSMutableString`. Is there really any performance difference unless the code's going to be running in a 10k loop or am I wasting my time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the mutable types where you want to be able to change the contents in place. Use the immutable types otherwise.

In some cases you don't have a choice - such as the data object that holds the returned data from an NSURLRequest: Using a mutable data object is a lot easier than creating a lot of immutable data types and joining them up at the end.

After that, run your code through the profiler and see whether you should do anything differently. i.e. whether the overhead of creating new immutable types to hold objects is more efficient than using a mutable type. Anything else is a premature optimisation.

Comment: I'm really talking about when I have data that I've been manipulating in one method and I'm passing it back to another.

Comment: @Echilon As I've said, it depends on what you are doing. If the method that you are returning the data to needs to amend it in place, return a mutable object. Personally, I tend to keep my data types immutable when I'm passing them around. I prefer immutable types for properties as much as possible. Keeps things a lot more thread safe, and in cases where values are getting hammered from differenct places, it makes debugging easier. the mutable/immutable class clusters have the methods `copy` and `mutableCopy` that are very handy for this.

Comment: The first sentence here is the key: think about what you want to do with the data. If it needs to be mutable, then make it mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said its only worth if you call use Mutable many times. But if you call it only a few times this isnt any Problem.

You should think about alternatives, e.g. in a larger TableViews `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fristString, secondString]`, Instead of `*foo = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]` and `[foo append:firstString]` and so on.

Comment: TableView as an example doesn't seem to make much sense because of the caching and reusing of cells and rendering of only visible cells.

Comment: Not at all, what I ment if you build the String that should be Displayes via NSMutableString.

Comment: I don't get your point. The tableview gets altered only once per runloop — so not very often.

Comment: Ok I see TableViews arent a good example, because the User have to scroll that this Method gets called. An this is not much ;) Eventually if you have a long list (more then aprox. 5 Screenpages) and you scroll very quickly this COULD BE a problem.

Comment: Your example is not very advantageous either way. `[firstString stringByAppendingString:secondString]` will probably be better than either of the options you've presented.

Comment: you will have to have a very fast index finger